# How can I put sizeForItemAt on a background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to dynamically size a cell depending on the aspect ratio of the picture amongst other factors to create a custom layout. These calculations seem to be slowing down the loading of my app. I would like to move this process to a background thread. Below is code of the function.Is it possible to run this on background thread providing a temporary cell size until the calculations are complete so as not to slow down the overall performance of the app thank you for your help.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

  return self.collectionViewSizeCalculator!.sizeForPhoto(at: indexPath)
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICollectionView` (or `UITableView`) delegate and data source methods that have a return value must have a value returned on the main queue that it was called on and that return value should be calculated instantly (or as close as possible to instantly). Any delay causes lag in the collection view (or table view).

One solution is to store the cell sizes as part of your data model. Initially populate the sizes with an initial estimated size. Have your `sizeForItemAt` return whatever size you currently have in your data model.

Meanwhile, run a process in the background (for all cells or do this individually for each cell as it is needed) to calculate the real size of the cell(s). As you get back real values, update the data model and reload that cell on the main queue.

Comment: The part in which I am confused about is how to have it update the cells in the background and how do you know when the process on the background thread is complete.

Comment: You don't update the cells in the background. All UI updated must be done on the main queue.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help it loads much better now.